# Programatically add an SSL certificate to a WWW server

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, ssl-certificate

I've done a lot of research and haven't found anything that suites my needs.

Let's say, I have a server at https://example.com. How do I add an SSL certificate to the HttpListener on the server using *just* C#. I can't use any third parties because of what I'm creating.

**The server is not ASP.NET**, it is a server that my software will communicate with.

Comment: If this can be done and how this can be done fully depends on the (unknown) server software.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I want to add an SSL to a System.Net.HttpListener using no third parties. I already have a certificate, I just want to implement it

Comment: Have you accomplished anything related to this question? I need the exact same thing now.

Comment: @PabloSantaCruz I ended up completely rewriting the HttpListener using Sockets as you can add an SslStream to a TCP stream